# Undefined reference to '_*' linker error

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, header-files

I am having trouble compiling/linking the following C code.  The linker throws errors that look like the following:

```
pso.o:pso.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to '_ps'
...
pso.o:pso.c:(.text+0x93): more undefined references to '_ps' follow
```

This is my first time writing C code for gcc, so I'm unsure how to fix this problem.  I am assuming that because struct PS is defined my header file, it is somehow not linked to pso.c.  However, I did use a #include "ps.h" statement at the top of that source file.

I have included the relevant source files and header file below, as well as the make file I am using.  Is there a fundamental concept I am missing for writing linkable C code?

Thank you!  Oh, and it's a particle swarm optimizer, if you were wondering :)

The main.c file:

```
#define MAIN
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include "ps.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c;
  double test;
  int test_int;

  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("starting pso\n");
  pso();
  printf("finished pso\n");
  return(0);
}
```

The file in question, pso.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "ps.h"

double it(double C[]);

void pso()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    puts("Now in PSO");

    /* Initialize PSO controls */
    psoi();

    /* Initialize particle positions and velocities */
    for (i=0;i<MPART;i++){
        for(j=1;j<MINDV;j++){
            /* positions */
            ps.X[i][j]=(-1+2*random())*ps.bup;

            /* velocities */
            ps.V[i][j] = (-1+2*random())*ps.bup / ps.vred;

            /* Transform */
            ps.ut[j] = (ps.X[i][j] - ps.blo)/(ps.bup - ps.blo) * (ps.bnd_hi[i] - ps.bnd_lo[i]) + ps.bnd_lo[i];
        }

        /* Evaluate Finess */
        ps.fitness = fit(ps.ut);

        /* Update particle best position */
        ps.pbest[i]=ps.fitness;

        /* Update swarm best position */
        if(ps.pbest[i] < ps.sbest){
            for(j=0;j<MINDV;j++){
                ps.g[j]=ps.p[i][j];
            }
            ps.sbest = ps.pbest[i];
        }
    }

    /* Convergenve Loop */

    for(k=2;k<ps.maxk;k++){
        for(i=1;i<MPART;i++){
            for(j=1;j<MINDV;j++){
                /* Velocity Update */
                ps.rp = random();
                ps.rg = random();
                ps.rr = random();
                ps.chi = 0.7298;

                ps.V[i][j] = ps.chi * ( ps.V[i][j] + ps.phi_p*ps.rp*(ps.p[i][j] - ps.X[i][j]) + ps.phi_g*ps.rg*(ps.g[j] - ps.X[i][j]));

                /* Position Update */
                ps.X[i][j] = ps.X[i][j] + ps.V[i][j];
                /* Transform */
                ps.ut[j] = (ps.X[i][j]-ps.blo)/(ps.bup-ps.blo)*(ps.bnd_hi[i]-ps.bnd_lo[i])+ps.bnd_lo[i];
                }

            /* Evaluate Fitness */
            ps.fitness = fit(ps.ut);

            /* Update particle best position */
            if(ps.fitness < ps.pbest[i]){
                for(j=0;j<MINDV;j++){
                    ps.p[i][j]=ps.X[i][j];
                }
                ps.pbest[i]=ps.fitness;
            }

            /* Update swarm best position */
            if(ps.pbest[i] < ps.sbest){
                for(j=0;j<MINDV;j++){
                ps.g[j]=ps.p[i][j];
                }
            ps.sbest = ps.pbest[i];
            printf("%f \n",ps.sbest);
            }
        }

        /* Convergence Criteria */

    }
  /* return(0); */
 }
```

The header file which defines the data structure PS (ps.h):

```
#ifndef _PS_
#define _PS_
#define MPART 30
#define MINDV 2

typedef struct{
  /* Design Space */
  double X[MPART][MINDV];
  double V[MPART][MINDV];
  double p[MPART][MINDV];
  double u[MINDV];
  double ut[MINDV];
  double sbest;
  double sbest_old;
  double g[MINDV];
  double gt[MINDV];
  double pbest[MPART];
  double pbest_sort[MPART];
  double blo;
  double bup;
  double fitness;
  double maxk;
  double bnd_lo[MINDV];
  double bnd_hi[MINDV];
  /* PSO behavior */
  int psotype;
  double w;
  double phi_p;
  double phi_g;
  double gam;
  double chi;
  double vred;
  double rp;
  double rg;
  double rr;
}PS;

/* Dependent Source File Functions */
extern void pso();
extern double fit(double C[2]);

#ifndef MAIN
extern PS ps;
#endif
#endif
```

Lastly, the make file I am using:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -I.
DEPS = ps.h
OBJ = main.o pso.o psoi.o fit.o

default: program

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

program: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "ps.h", you have the line

```
extern PS ps;
```

— but this only *declares* `ps` (i.e. assert it exists somewhere); it doesn't provide a *definition* (i.e. make it exist here). What you should do is, step one, replace

```
#ifndef MAIN
extern PS ps;
#endif
```

with just

```
extern PS ps;
```

and then, step two, go into `pso.c` and somewhere at the top level of that file add

```
PS ps = {};
```

(or `PS ps;`, or `extern PS ps = {};`). If your C compiler is old or dumb enough to complain about the empty braces, write `PS ps = {0};` instead; `{}` is a C++'03-ism that I believe is being adopted into C'11 but I'm not 100% certain about that.

Briefly, the rule about declarations is: If you provide an initializer with `=`, then the declaration must be a definition (because how else could you initialize the variable here?). Otherwise, if you used the `extern` storage-class, it's *not* a definition (because mnemonically, you're saying that the variable exists *extern*-ally to this file). Otherwise, it's a definition (but in K&R C it's a [tentative definition](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03tentative_defn.htm), and many compilers will either put it in the BSS section by default or else provide a command-line option to do so).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!  This worked although I also had to remove 'extern' from 'extern PS ps'.

Answer (score 2):

The linker output is slightly confusing, it's really complaining about the definition of the object `ps` being missing.  You've declared it `extern`, but never defined it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you!  I should not have declared it an extern, as it was already defined the the header file...

Answer (score 2):

You only *declare* `ps` as `extern`, but you never actually *define* it anywhere. Write

```
PS ps;
```

in one of the C files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and succinct answer.  This was the problem but I also had to remove the "extern" keyword from "PS ps" in the header file.