# What is the appropriate library for linking Postgres server-side C functions

Tags: c, postgresql

I am trying to compile some C extensions, on platform with Ubuntu 14.04, for Postgres 9.5.

In my case, I want to write my C code and compile it first to a standalone executable (as you can see from my Makefile below). This is because I am also using the NumPy API and writing functions that convert Postgres `ArrayType` arrays into NumPy `PyArray` objects, and then use some NumPy array functions. It's very tricky to get the details right, deallocate `NpyIter` objects correctly, etc., so I definitely need to compile, run, observe errors, and test all *before* finalizing the details of how the library is built for the final part where I say `CREATE EXTENSION` in Postgres.

When compiling, I get several [undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257120/undefined-reference-to-linker-error) issues, such as:

```
tmp.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `get_typlenbyvalalign'
tmp.c:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `deconstruct_array'
tmp.c:(.text+0x41f): undefined reference to `DatumGetFloat8'
tmp.c:(.text+0x4ae): undefined reference to `pfree'
tmp.c:(.text+0x4ba): undefined reference to `pfree'
```

These are server-side functions from the Postgres C API, but with lots of Googling and lots of strongarming of `pgxs` I cannot figure out how to obtain the name or path of the backend Postgres library that I'm failing to link.

Almost all searches just mention `libpq`, but these functions are not defined in that client-side API library, so I'm looking for something else.

For reference, here's the Makefile I'm currently using. Including the library directory from `pg_config --libdir` must also be incorrect, as it does not cause any changes in the undefined reference errors.

```
INCLUDEDIRS := -I.
INCLUDEDIRS += -I/usr/include/python2.7
INCLUDEDIRS += -I/home/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
INCLUDEDIRS += -I$(shell pg_config --includedir-server)
INCLUDEDIRS += -I$(shell pg_config --includedir)

LIBS := -L$(shell pg_config --libdir)
LIBS += -lpython2.7

tmp: tmp.c Makefile
    gcc tmp.c -o tmp $(INCLUDEDIRS) $(LIBS)
```

Output of `pg_config --libdir` is:

```
user@computer:~/programming$ pg_config --libdir
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

In that library directory I also found `libpgcommon` and when I add it to the Makefile, some of the undefined references disappear, but not all. These still remain:

```
tmp.c:(.text+0x2d6): undefined reference to `get_typlenbyvalalign'
tmp.c:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `deconstruct_array'
tmp.c:(.text+0x41f): undefined reference to `DatumGetFloat8'
```

So `pfree` was found by linking with `libpgcommon`, but nothing else.

Digging even further, inside of `postgres.h` I can see where the `DatumGetFloat8` macro is defined (line 662):

```
#ifdef USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL
extern float8 DatumGetFloat8(Datum X);
#else
#define DatumGetFloat8(X) (* ((float8 *) DatumGetPointer(X)))
#endif
```

So, it must be the case that Postgres was installed in some way that made use of the `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` flag. Is that standard? Would you expect that from a plain Postgres install using package repos for a popular OS like Ubuntu?

Given this, what is the other source code or library from which `DatumGetFloat8` is `extern`'d from? For example, searching Google for "postgres DatumGetFloat8" sheds pretty much no light on this. The best I can find is a [message thread from 2011](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Fwd-Re-Calling-it-a-day-td4360247.html) stating (not sure if correctly):

> A missing reference to DatumGetFloat8 implies that the server was built
>   with float8 pass by value and pljava was built with float8 pass by
>   reference.

(The `pljava` bit is irrelevant for me).

Comment: I would guess that that a server side extension is some plugin `dlopen`ed by the PostGreSQL *server* process?

Answer (score 3):

A PostgreSQL extension is a shared library and not a standalone executable, so you got to use `-shared -fpic -o tmp.so` in your Makefile.  Don't link with `-lpq` or `-lpgcommon`.

Then `gcc` won't complain about undefined references – these will be resolved with the executable `postgres` when the shared library is loaded into PostgreSQL, either with the SQL command `LOAD` or when a PostgreSQL C function defined with that library is called.

Of course you'll have to use the same `-D` defines as the PostgreSQL server when it was built, so that for example `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` is set or unset in both. Otherwise your extension may fail to load or could crash in interesting ways.
(Since you were asking: there is nothing bad about passing `float8` by value; it is actually more efficient that way if your architecture supports it. `DatumGetFloat8` is defined and exported in `postgres` if `USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL` is defined.)

To make all that easy, it is best to use the PostgreSQL extension building infrastructure [PGXS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html). That will take care of all these problems for you.

All you have to do is create an appropriate `Makefile`, in your case it might be as simple as

```
MODULES = tmp

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

Then run `make` and `make install`, and you are ready to go!

Since your problem is to test and debug your code that uses the NumPy API, you should modularize your PostgreSQL extension so that you can do that more easily. You could for example write `numpy.c` which contains all the code that accesses that API and `pgxs.c` which contains the PostgreSQL extension code and calls functions in `numpy.c`.
Then you can write special testing code and link it with `numpy.o` to test your NumPy functions.

Comment: Suppose I want to include a `main` function and build the extension first as a standalone executable, but still calling server-side C-API Postgres functions, to test it in pure C first, before building it as a shared object and installing it with Postgres. You can see from my Makefile this is what I am trying to do. How can I build that standalone executable?

Comment: @Mr.F. you cannot do that. You might run a "private" PostGreSQL server for testing purposes (e.g. configured on non-standard ports & files)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Suppose, just for example, that I need to create a Postgres type, like a single `Datum`, and print it to `STDOUT`. We could pretend for this question that I just need to write a C program to do only that, as a standalone executable not yet built as an extension in the database server. Given that there must be a server library *somewhere* that has defined symboles for e.g. `DatumGetFloat8` it doesn't make sense to say "you can't". Maybe it requires a ton of boilerplate to embed the Postgres server or something? But there must be *some* library with the definitions.

Comment: No, what defines those symbols is the PostGreSQL *server* executable (which is *not* a library). Read more about plugins and `dlopen`.  See [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Study the source code of [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) since it is free software. Read http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

Comment: @Mr. F: The way to print a `Datum` to `stdout` is to use a PostgreSQL server and `psql` and say `SELECT ...`. Maybe you could explain your use case, there might be some way to achieve what you want. However, if you want to use PostgreSQL as embedded server (as a library in your C program), you cannot do that. It is impossible.

Comment: I don't mean to sound impolite; the medium of a comment forces me to be concise. The PostgreSQL server's C API cannot be used by standalone executables. I personally develop a PostgreSQL extension that involves a complicated third-party product (Oracle database), and I think you might overestimate how complicated it is to test it using PostgreSQL. All you have to do is replace the shared library and start a new database session, things that can easily done with an automated test suite.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How do you experiment to detect things like memory leaks with the third-party stuff? The extension function might appear to work perfectly fine for most test cases when used from within Postgres, but you might be overlooking a failure to properly deallocate some complex resource in the third-party tools. If your only means of execution is embedded within the running Postgres server executable, what kind of dev workflow can you use to efficiently investigate these things, make alterations, iterate, memory profile, etc.?

Comment: I use `valgrind` for that. I start PostgreSQL in single user mode (`postgres --single -D datadir dbname`), switch to the desired user with `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION username` and run my test cases.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Unfortunately, valgrind is most often not helpful for detecting the memory leaks and refcount issues when using NumPy, that's one of the reasons you have to write a lot of your own tooling, then execute your own standalone code to inspect things, and a reason why I need to link these Postgres symbols outside of the running Postgres server library, or else embed that server library into my standalone C code.

Comment: I see. The problem is that there is no server library. I guess you would be best served to have your code in two modules with a clear interface, one for NumPy and one for PostgreSQL server code. Then you can test and debug these individually without cumbersome dependencies.

Comment: Or make a server library from the c source?  I think this is essentially what the question comes down to if I'm understanding.  Unfortunately, it sounds like this isn't supported by the current build system, so you might have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: FYI: I'd also like an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a Postgres *extension* (the kind where you say `CREATE EXTENSION foo`), you don't need to worry too much about all the `INCLUDEDIR` etc. stuff. It is easier than you think! I've written a couple very simple Postgres extensions, despite doing C only a few times a year, and it's actually pretty easy. Your `Makefile` can be literally 6 lines long, like this:

```
MODULES = myextensionname
EXTENSION = myextensionname
DATA = myextensionname--1.0.sql
PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

You should also have a `myextensionname.control` file that is something like this:

```
comment = 'Something about your extension'
default_version = '1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/myextensionname'
relocatable = true
```

And you need a `myextensionname.c` like so:

```
#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <catalog/pg_type.h>
#include <utils/builtins.h>
// whatever other things you need to include here

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

// your code here
```

Then you write a `myextensionname--1.0.sql` file that is run when someone says `CREATE EXTENSION`, and that's where you create types/functions/whatever else you need (in SQL).

If you want a couple really easy examples to copy from, here are my two projects:

https://github.com/pjungwir/aggs_for_arrays

https://github.com/pjungwir/inetrange

If you want more advanced extension examples, look in the `contrib` dir of [a local Postgres checkout](https://github.com/postgres/postgres).

Regarding your question about this specifically:

> So, it must be the case that Postgres was installed in some way that made use of the USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL flag.

If you use a `Makefile` like the one above, you don't need to worry about that, because your extension will be compiled with the same flags, so it will treat `DatumGetFloat8` the same way as your installed Postgres (whether as a function or a macro). I think you will find that `USE_FLOAT_BYVAL` is just the tip of the iceberg, so rather than setting individual flags, you should use `include $(PGXS)` to get everything to match.

**EDIT:** I just saw your comment that you want to write a standalone binary for testing purposes. I think I would do that *after* making a working extension, so you can get more familiar with the process. Also, you can look in my own projects and the `contrib` extensions for examples of how other people handle testing.