# Postgresql 9.6 C function compile error: elog.h: unknown type 'sigjmp'

Tags: c, postgresql

all,
I am trying to compile the following C skeleton against Postgresql 9.6.

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "miscadmin.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(calculateValHash);
Datum calculateValHash(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {

text *t = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);
if ( t ) {
  PG_RETURN_INT32(12);
} else {
  PG_RETURN_INT32(1);
}
```

};

The following gcc command returns with error:

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server -lpq -o ./_build/magick.so pgmagick.c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
In file included from /usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server/postgres.h:48:0,
                 from pgmagick.c:1:
/usr/include/postgresql/9.6/server/utils/elog.h:318:20: error: unknown type name ‘sigjmp_buf’
 extern PGDLLIMPORT sigjmp_buf *PG_exception_stack;
                ^
```

OS:Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
I have postgresql-server-dev-9.6 also installed.

Comment: No need to write your own gcc commands, let [PGXS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html) worry about all of the messy details. You can find an example of a minimal PGXS Makefile here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38222564

Comment: To accept an answer, please click the tick mark adjacent to the answer below. We do not add solutions or [solved] marks to questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man setjmp`,

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>   siglongjmp(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_C_SOURCE
> ```

Try to `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before `#include "postgres.h"`.